# The difference between the two dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

Is there an equivalent to this T-SQL command in PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [dbo].[LayerTable] 
where layerType=3 
 and created >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp))),0)
```

I have found date_part() and extract function() but not working.

Comment: No everybody that knows Postgres will know what that T-SQL query is doing. Can you explain in words what the `dateadd()` function is doing? Does it add six months to `current_timestamp`?

Comment: DATEADD (datepart , number , date ) : Returns a new datetime value by adding an interval to the specified datepart of the specified date.

DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate ) : Returns the number of date or time datepart boundaries, crossed between two specified dates.

Comment: Your SQL seems to be invalid: When I run `select Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp))))` I get an error "The dateadd function requires 3 argument(s).": https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=db20a2aeadb5bfee57bf412bf7d46947

Comment: Im so so Sorry. 
select Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)),0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is simply subtracting 6 months from current_timestamp, so the equivalent would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.layer_table
where layer_type=3 
  and created >= current_timestamp - interval '6 months';
```

If you want the start of the month (rather than the "same" day as "today") as the result use:

```
created >= date_trunc('month', current_timestamp - interval '6 months')
```